# Picking n_neighbors for KNeighborsClassifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Simple question I couldn't find an answer anywhere online.
Based on your data, how do you pick which number to use for n_neighbors? Or is it best to use the default of 5? 
The data set I am working with uses 13 values to predict the target.

Comment: `Based on your data, how do you pick which number to use for n_neighbors`. Short answer: Pick the number that works best. The difficult part is to get the `best` right. You may want to have a look at the difference between training and testing and `crossvalidation` to find good (optimal) parameters.

Comment: You should not look at the error on the testing set when choosing model parameters such as number of neighbors, only training and validation or cross validation. Choose the number of parameter that minimizes the (cross) validation error. I suggest reading [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_%28statistics%29)

Answer (score 3):

You should try different parameters and evaluate them via cross validation. Sklearn has a class for that: [GridSearchCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV):

```
g = GridSearchCV(KNeighborsClassifier(), { "n_neighbors" : [5, 7, 11, 13, 17] })
g.fit(X, y)
```

It's easy to customize scoring function and (most importantly) run evaluations in parallel.